# Changing the name of a sharepoint list programmaticaly

Tags: list, development

I'm trying to change the "name" of a sharepoint document library (not the title). I have found a way to do it from sharepoint designer: http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a-d0ef-4258-be2a-28487dc9975c&ID=52 What I need is to do this programmaticaly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use method [SPFolder.MoveTo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfolder.moveto.aspx) for this purpose.

Example code:

```
SPList list = web.Lists["Important Items"];
list.RootFolder.MoveTo("II");
```

P.S. Tested, works as expected.